# Passing variable value from python to shell script to use it there

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, amazon-web-services

I am creating some aws queues of this way:

```
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

def create_queue(name, attributes=None):
    if not attributes:
        attributes = {}
    try:
        queue = sqs.create_queue(
            QueueName=name,
            Attributes=attributes
        )
        # logger.info("Created queue '%s' with URL=%s", name, queue.url)
    except ClientError as error:
        logger.exception("Is not possible create the queue '%s' ", name)
        raise error
    else:
        return queue

def creating_queues():
    prefix = 'test_order_'

    # Creating test_order_myqueue queue
    myqueue_queue = create_queue(
        prefix + 'myqueue',
        {
            'MaximumMessageSize': str(1024),
            'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': str(20)
        }
    )
    response = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=prefix + 'myqueue')
    print("Created the queue with URL:", response['QueueUrl'])

    # Getting the URL of the queue
    sqsid = boto3.resource('sqs')
    queue = sqsid.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='test_order_myqueue')

    # THIS IS THE VARIABLE VALUE I WANT TO PASS TO SHELL SCRIPT
    url = queue.url

    print ("URL:", url)
    print ("start sending messages")

    rc = call("./send.sh")
```

I want to use the `url` variable value in the `send.sh` script of this way:
The `send.sh` script is a loop which send messages to the queue which was created above

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
   echo "Sending $i house entry"

   # I WANT TO USE THE url variable value from python here, instead of use the url hardcoded here
   aws sqs send-message-batch --queue-url https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/138290733079/test_devops_makelaars    --entries file://send-houses-batch.json  > ./test.output
done
cat ./test.output
```

I want to use the the `url` variable value from python in the shell script, instead of use the url hardcoded.

So that I am trying is the following: **I will put again the `creating_queues()` method**

```
def creating_queues():
    prefix = 'test_devops_'

    # Creating test_order_myqueue queue
    myqueue_queue = create_queue(
        prefix + 'myqueue',
        {
            'MaximumMessageSize': str(1024),
            'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': str(20)
        }
    )
    response = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=prefix + 'myqueue')
    print("Created the queue with URL:", response['QueueUrl'])
    sqsid = boto3.resource('sqs')
    queue = sqsid.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='test_devops_makelaars')

    url = queue.url
    print ("URL:", url)
    print ("start sending messages")

    # rc = call("./send.sh")

    # I TRY TO SEND THE url variable as string 
    call("send.sh", str(url))
```

So in my `send.sh` string I reference the `url` variable in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
   echo "Sending $i house entry"
   # aws sqs send-message-batch --queue-url https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/138290733079/test_devops_makelaars  --entries file://send-houses-batch.json  > ./test.output

   # I AM INCLUDING THE URL VARIABLE HERE $url
   aws sqs send-message-batch --queue-url $url  --entries file://send-houses-batch.json  > ./test.output

done
cat ./test.output
```

But I got this error

```
start sending messages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue-workflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    creating_queues()
  File "queue-workflow.py", line 50, in creating_queues
    call("send.sh", str(url))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 753, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

How can I pass the url variable from python and how do I need to deal with it in the shell file?

Comment: You want to pass an array as the first arg to `call()` (look at the docs) and reference it in your script as `$1` (look at anything related to bash arguments).

Comment: Yes, I did it should have in this way  `rc = call(["./send.sh", str(url)])` . Thanks @hmm :)